# I am working on editing source code of a mod from cities skyline but cant create the button UI

Tags: c#, cities-skylines-api

Below is the Original source code the creator provided.

```
namespace DistrictUITweaks
{
    public class DUITMod : ICities.IUserMod
    {
        public string Description {
            get { return "Enhanced UI with options to hide district icons and names, including policies"; }
        }
 
        public string Name {
            get { return "District UI Tweaks"; }
        }
    }
 
    public class DUITThread : ICities.ThreadingExtensionBase
    {
        public override void OnUpdate(float realTimeDelta, float simulationTimeDelta)
        {
            base.OnUpdate(realTimeDelta, simulationTimeDelta);
 
            bool active = ColossalFramework.Singleton<DistrictManager>.instance.DistrictsVisible ||
                ColossalFramework.Singleton<DistrictManager>.instance.DistrictsInfoVisible;
            ColossalFramework.Singleton<DistrictManager>.instance.NamesVisible = active;
        }
    }
}
```

[Mod Link](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=433557907)

using chatgbt I was able to get this input:

```
using UnityEngine;
using ColossalFramework.UI;

namespace DistrictUITweaks
{
    public class DUITMod : ICities.IUserMod
    {
        private UIButton toggleButton; // Button reference for toggling district icons and names visibility

        public string Description {
            get { return "Enhanced UI with options to hide district icons and names, including policies"; }
        }

        public string Name {
            get { return "District UI Tweaks"; }
        }

        public void OnEnabled()
        {
            // Create the button and set its properties
            toggleButton = UIView.GetAView().AddUIComponent(typeof(UIButton)) as UIButton;
            toggleButton.text = "Toggle Districts";
            toggleButton.width = 150f;
            toggleButton.height = 30f;
            toggleButton.relativePosition = new Vector3(10f, 10f);
            toggleButton.eventClick += ToggleDistricts;
        }

        public void OnDisabled()
        {
            // Clean up the button when the mod is disabled
            if (toggleButton != null)
            {
                toggleButton.eventClick -= ToggleDistricts;
                GameObject.Destroy(toggleButton.gameObject);
                toggleButton = null;
            }
        }

        private void ToggleDistricts(UIComponent component, UIMouseEventParameter eventParam)
        {
            bool isVisible = !ColossalFramework.Singleton<DistrictManager>.instance.NamesVisible;
            ColossalFramework.Singleton<DistrictManager>.instance.NamesVisible = isVisible;
        }
    }

    // ThreadingExtensionBase is not necessary for the button functionality,
    // but I assume you may have more code in your implementation.
    public class DUITThread : ICities.ThreadingExtensionBase
    {
        // Add any necessary code for the threading extension
    }
}
```

I'm expecting maybe I'm a couple steps away from having this work?
(I am new to coding overall, I used python for school but this is my very first time working with C#, just let me know what I can do to improve this code, how I can make it work and implement it, I already downloaded visual code and tried to compile it in a file and add it to the game but when the mod is enabled  it just gives me an error code for why the mod isn't working